# Maven & Spring import resource XML from external file

Tags: java, spring, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to import part of my spring context from external file. at the bottom of my spring xml I have:

```
<import resource="${file}" />
```

I want to specify ${file} using command line argument and I use JVM properties for that.
I'm making an executable jar using maven assembly plugin.

Then I run it  and I specify a file with JVM parameter:

```
java -jar [app.jar] -Dfile=model-a.xml
```

This works fine when I debug using eclipse.

But when I pack my file using maven spring cannot resolve the path and for some reason it tries to locate the file in "spring/model-a.xml"
I build my jar using maven-assembly-plugin.

Why running using java -jar adds "spring/" to my path ?

Comment: Can you add your spring.xml and the tree of your repertories? I believe spring/ get added because it is relativePath and your file is src/main/resources/spring/spring.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved after changing the spring configuration to:

```
<import resource="file:${file}" />
```

And using java -jar [jar] -Dfile=`realpath model-a.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the copy of the file in `target/classes`; you will probably find that `${file}` is gone and has been replaced with `model-a`.

To fix this, I suggest to use a longer name for the variable, preferably one which tells other people what the meaning for this could be.